# classpath - running a java program from the command line

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classnotfoundexception

My code compiled fine with the following command:

`javac -cp "../lib/*" AvroReader.java`

(lib is where i put my jar files)

At run time I get a `ClassNotFoundException` on the following line:

`DatumReader<?> dtmrdr = new GenericDatumReader();`

It says it can't find `org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader` even though I've imported it.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How are you running the program? You have to provide the classpath with all your dependencies when you run your application as well.

Comment: I ran it by running 
    `java Generator`
.
Generator is a class that calls a method in AvroReader.java

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Importing has nothing to do with loading classes or setting CLASSPATH.

Try this:

```
java -cp .;../lib/* Generator
```

Using the dot `'.'` as the first entry in the CLASSPATH assumes that the `Generator.class` file exists in the directory from which you're running java, and `/lib` is one level up from that directory.  Adjust as needed if both of these are not correct.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "using . as the first entry in the CLASSPATH"

Comment: Look very carefully at the compilation string I posted.  See the dot just before the semi-colon?  That's the step you missed that caused the JVM to not be able to find your Generator.class.

Comment: @DaoLam - The argument after `-cp` is the classpath.  It is a list of directories separated by `;` characters.  The first item is `.` which means `the current directory`.  The second item is `../lib/*` which means everything in the `../lib` directory.  Duffymo is telling you that you need to include the `current directory` (the location of Generator.class) to your classpath.

Comment: @duffymo: you don't have to be so harsh & discouraging. The fact that I'm here shows that I'm not a pro at Java yet and I'm still learning. After reading jahroy's comment, I realized what it means and I already know it from before. My brain was probably just dead at the time I posted that comment.

Comment: Thanks though. It works but there's something I don't understand. After reading other posts (before you posted yours), I added the current directory to the classpath (which is supposed to be the same as "."), but it didn't work. Why is that?

Comment: On Mac OS the file separator is colon(:) and need to enclose directories in quotes. So do `java -cp .:"../lib/*" Generator`

Comment: Yes.  Nobody seemed to mind that missing detail when I answered this five years ago.  Surely there are better uses for your time here than writing comments like these.

Answer (score 8):

You should run the program including again the same cp:

```
java -cp "lib directory where i put all the jars" MainClassOfYourApplication
```

After you compiled it with:

```
javac -cp "lib directory where i put all the jars" AvroReader.java
```

More applied to your example:

```
First step(compile all the needed java files): javac -cp "path/to/jars/*" AvroReader.java //here you should include all the java files not yet compiled but which you need to run your app
Second step: java -cp "path/to/jars/*" package.subpackage1.subpackage2.Generator
```

Comment: You can't just use a directory of jars; you'd need a wildcard. A directory classpath entry is only for class files, AFAIK--a pointer to docs stating otherwise would be helpful. I'm looking at the [1.7 classpath docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: I'm calling a method from AvroReader in another class. This is how I ran it: 

    `javac -cp "jar directory" AvroReader.java`

    `javac Generator.java`

    `java Generator`

I tried what you suggested java -cp "jar directory" Generator, but now it's saying that it can't find Generator.

Comment: @Dave Newton: Yea I actually have a wildcard. It's basically something like "../lib/*"
Sorry I wasn't being clear in my original post.

Comment: @DaoLam - If you're just calling `java Generator` it won't work because you're not specifying a classpath.  Your comment seems to contradict the info in your question, however...

Comment: @jahroy Can you be more specific on how to run it? Thank you! :)

Comment: @DaoLam - Read this answer, it tells you what to do: You need to include the classpath when you run the program **AND** when you compile it.

Answer (score -1):

To compile and execute java file on Linux System with external jar files :

```
javac -cp jar_file1.jar:jar_file2:jar_file3.jar:. java_program_name.java

java -cp new_mail_api.jar:activation.jar:additional.jar:.java_program_name
```

To compile and execute java file on Windows System with external jar files :

```
javac -cp jar_file1.jar;jar_file2;jar_file3.jar;. java_program_name.java

java -cp new_mail_api.jar;activation.jar;additional.jar;.java_program_name
```

In Unix of Linux, Java Classpath contains names of the directory with colon “:” separated, On Windows Java Classpath will be semicolon “;” separated while if you defined java classpath in Manifest file those will be space separated.

For more  knowledge about Classpath, visit https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html