# Runtime Error "Class Not found" while writing java program to connect DB2 and fetch data

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-midrange

The below code is compiled successfully.

Code Source(`Jdbcexample.java`) and compiled class file (`JdbcExample.class`) directory:-"test"
When I ran this program using `java JdbcExample`, it throws class not found `com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver` and in job log:

> code ended with 04:Unable to find class required to run Java Program".

The problem is related to class path I suppose.

can anyone please guide me how should set path/classpath and run program to avoid above error?

```
import java.sql.*;  

public class JDBCexample {  
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Connection con = null;  
    try {  
          Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver);  
        }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {  
          System.out.println(e);  
          System.exit(0);  
        }  
    try {  
          con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:as400://yourserver", "yourUserId","yourPassword");  

          Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM YOURLIB.YOUR_PF_FILE");  

          while (rs.next())
         {  

                  String field1 = rs.getString(1);  
                  String field2 = rs.getString("fieldname");  


          }
           rs.close();
           stmt.close();
           con.close();
       }
          catch(Exception e)
          {  

          }  

          }  
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [classpath - running a java program from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462421/classpath-running-a-java-program-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Use Eclipse for good.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it cannot find the JDBC driver.  That driver is part of the IBM Toolkit for Java.  In my case, I am using JTOpen instead of the version that ships with the machine.  I put jt400.jar in the IFS in a directory called *java*.

If running from IBM i (not PASE or QShell), you set your classpath with ADDENVVAR.  This works for me because I put my .jar files in /java:

```
ADDENVVAR ENVVAR(CLASSPATH) VALUE('.:+       
                                  /java:+   
                                  /java/*')
```

The jt400 that is shipped with the machine is in the IFS.  On my 7.2 machine, the path is: `/QIBM/ProdData/HTTP/Public/jt400/lib` - if you want to use that version, put that path in your CLASSPATH.  IBM maintain a [FAQ on the Toolbox](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/toolbox/faq/).

Answer (score 0):

Set your classpath with the below command and execute your java program.

```
SET CLASSPATH=%DIR%\lib\yourlib.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Class.forName("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver);

have you added the relevant jar for AS400JDBCDriver in your project.check it once

Answer (score 0):

try

```
java -cp pathtojarlib:. JdbcExample
```

where pathtojarlib is the path of your connector library

Answer (score 0):

I thought you have done some silly mistake.
Please check your class name. 
IN the above given code the class name is `JDBCexample`
and you use `java JdbcExample` to run ..
Use `java JDBCexample`

Answer (score 0):

Add classpath to your jar's MANIFEST.MF.  Example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: JdbcExample
Class-Path: lib/db2jcc.jar lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
```