# How to inform Java to look for a specific package in a specific directory

Tags: java

Very new to Java and I'm trying out few java basic programs on the Ubuntu 18.04 VM, not on any IDEs(at-least for time being).

One of the sample program requires snakeyaml and I've installed via apt and its available in below locations.

```
dpkg -L libyaml-snake-java
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libyaml-snake-java
/usr/share/doc/libyaml-snake-java/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/libyaml-snake-java/copyright
/usr/share/java
/usr/share/java/snakeyaml.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo
/usr/share/maven-repo/org
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/yaml
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/yaml/snakeyaml
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23.pom
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.x
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.x/snakeyaml-1.x.pom
/usr/share/java/snakeyaml-1.23.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23.jar
/usr/share/maven-repo/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.x/snakeyaml-1.x.jar
```

How can I consume the same in my code, just a plain import like `import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;` is throwing

```
error: package org.yaml.snakeyaml does not exist
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;
                         ^ 
error: cannot find symbol
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
```

Comment: Do you compile on command-line using `javac` ? Is it a Maven project with a `pom.xml` file ? Usually the classpath can be specified. And the JAR (here e.g.  `/usr/share/java/snakeyaml-1.23.jar`) must be included in the classpath.

Comment: See also [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462421/classpath-running-a-java-program-from-the-command-line) showing __how to specify the classpath__ with `-cp`

Comment: @hc_dev : `java -cp /usr/share/maven-repo/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23.jar Test
Error: Could not find or load main class Test`

what am i doing incorrect ?

Comment: Maybe you need to add the full package where your Test class is in, like `java -cp /usr/share/java/snakeyaml-1.23.jar my.package.Test`  (here the "my.package.") see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) when searching for the "Error: Could not find or load main class ".